# Introducing run-time calls into compile-time template calculation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Say I have this construct which computes `sizeof` things at compile-time

```
template<typename T>
struct GetTypeSize
{
    enum { value = sizeof(T) };
};

// treat float as special
template<>
struct GetTypeSize<float>
{
    enum { value = SIZEOF_FLOAT };
};


template<typename...>
struct GetSize
{
    enum { value = 0 };
};

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct GetSize<Head, Tail...>
{
    enum { value = GetTypeSize<Head>::value + GetSize<Tail...>::value };
};
```

Which is used like this

```
template <class ...T>
void foo(T... arg)
{
    const size_t size = GetSize<T...>::value;
    std::cout << "size of the thing is: " << size << std::endl;

    // do stuff with arg
}
```

This works fine (with primitive data types, obviously).

Now, I want it to be able to handle `std::vector<T>`, in such a way that it returns `vec.size() * sizeof(T)`. Obviously that will have to be a run time operation.

I could change the entire thing to being run time easily. If I wanted to do that I wouldn't have asked this question in the first place.

I also could have used two constructs, one compile-time and another run-time, in separate statements, where the latter would return 0 on everything but `std::vector<T>`. Such solution is not better than having the entire thing being run-time, since you would have to make a function call for every single `arg`, which defeats the entire point of the compile-time solution.

What I actually want is for it stay compile-time for as much as possible, i.e. having only `std::vector` being evaluated at run time. For example, the generated code for `arg = {uint32_t, uint64_t, uint16_t, std::vector<uint32_t>, uint16_t}` would be something like

```
const size_t size = 4 + 8 + 2 + (argN.size() * 4) + 2;
```

So I wonder if such a mix of compile-time and run-time in a single construct is possible and how to archive it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use c++14?

Comment: Practically, a function call to something that simply reads `{ return sizeof(T) }` will get inlined anyway, so it really shouldn't matter. You can add `constexpr` to encourage that further.

Comment: @DavidW yes, but you could evaluate `std::vector<T>::size() * sizeof(T)` in a `constexpr` function with C++14

Comment: 1) I was just trying to make the point that for performance you likely wouldn't need to. 2) Doesn't using `std::vector<T>::size()` in a `constexpr` rely on being able to evaluate the vector length at compile time, which in general isn't true?

Comment: @DavidW the point of suggesting it is because with C++14 `constexpr` can be *either* compile-time or run-time, rather than only run-time (regular function) or only compile-time (template meta-function). Which is exactly what OP wants.

Comment: Right OK - so you're saying the general `GetTypeSize` has a `constexpr` function to get the size (which you know will be evaluated at compile time), and the `std::vector` specialization for `GetTypeSize` has a normal function for size, which will be evaluated at runtime as you'd expect?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I'm restricted to using C++11, but C++14 version of the solution would be a nice extra.

Comment: @DavidW you got it man. I don't think you can have one solution for both cases (without a little hackery) in C++11, but I'm sure someone will prove me wrong! haha

Comment: I might have overthinked it then, if a compiler would actually inline functions that do only one thing -- returning a `sizeof`.